# Why doesn't this list check work?

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a text file, where there's "user" written on the first line. Then I pressed Enter and wrote "pass" on the second line and saved the file. (named "data").

```
username = input("please enter username: ")
password = input("please enter password: ")
textFile = open("data.txt", "r")
check = textFile.readlines()
data = []
for line in check:
    data.append(line)
if username == data[0] and password == data[1]:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong!")
```

It prints "Wrong" when I put the correct username and password. Why?

Comment: You should tag all your posts that contain real code with the appropriate language.

Comment: Make sure you aren't collecting the `\n` newline characters in your input. Try `username = input("please enter username: ").rstrip()`

Comment: Your function only works if username is on the first line and password is on the second line of the file.

Comment: Thanks guys for bringing it to my attention that there are new line characters at the end of my lines. Now I got it fixed and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're reading newline characters from your `data.txt` file. Try this:

```
for line in check:
    data.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

When you read the lines. This will strip out trailing new line characters.